# fullcalendar: How do i change view to 'listMonth' and then go to a default date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I would like my fullcalendar to change to the 'listMonth' View.

I would also like that the view will display and scroll to a specific date (or to the current date). For this question let's assume '2015-04-25'

Anybody know how to do that?

Here is my code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'listMonth');
```

Answer (score -1):

You need

`$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultDate: '2015-04-25',
  defaultView: 'listMonth'
})`